# Writing a game using Pygame and OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl

I tried to use the OpenGL to draw picture on a Pygame display to make a game. But when I suddenly realized that when the Pygame was linked to the OpenGL, I can't call my display anymore. Here are the errors I encountered :

```
pygame.error: Cannot blit to OPENGL Surfaces (OPENGLBLIT is ok) #when I try to blit on my surface
pygame.error: Cannot call on OPENGL Surfaces #when I wanted to fill my surface with a color
```

I found that OPENGLBLIT was deprecated (according to some users on the net). So, what should I use? I wanted to print the score at the top left hand corner.
Here is my original code :

```
1 : gameDisplay.blit(pygame.font.SysFont(None,25).render("values : "+str(score),True,self.green),[0,0])

2 : self.gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
```

How can I know any python module that are still commonly used and still being supported? (For example, for making a 3D tetris game)

Comment: From the error messages it sounds like you should use OpenGL to do the operations instead of pygame.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to use the opengl command. Moreover, I found that the mentioned command was deprecated. :'(

Comment: "deprecated" doesn't mean non-existent, so you can use it, and there's probably information or an example somewhere on how to call it. Also, things are usually deprecated when there's a better way to accomplish the task, so you might be able to find out what that is and use it instead.